# Spivak's calculus Chapter 1 exercise 21 proof verification

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification

> Prove that if
> $$|x - x_0| < \min \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}, 1\right)$$ and $$ |y - y_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)}$$
> then $|xy - x_0 y_0| < \varepsilon$

My proof: 

$xy - x_0y_0$ can be written as  $(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + (x-x_0)y_0 + (y-y_0)x_0$ 

so $$|xy-x_0y_0| \leq |(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + (x-x_0)y_0 + (y-y_0)x_0|$$
$$ \leq |x-x_0||y-y_0| + |x-x_0||y_0| +  |y-y_0||x_0| \; (\text{via triangle inequality})$$
$$ < |y-y_0| +|x-x_0||y_0| + |y-y_0||x_0| \; (\text{as }|x-x_0|< 1)$$
$$ < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)} +|x-x_0||y_0| + \frac{\varepsilon|x_0|}{2(|x_0| + 1)} \; (\text{as } |y-y_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)})$$
$$< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+ |x-x_0||y_0| \; (\text{as } \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)} + \frac{\varepsilon|x_0|}{2(|x_0| + 1)} =\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$$

from
$$ |x-x_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}$$
$$ |y_0| + 1<\frac{\varepsilon}{2|x-x_0|}$$
$$ |y_0| <\frac{\varepsilon}{2|x-x_0|} - 1 < \frac{\varepsilon}{2|x-x_0|}$$
so
$$|y_0||x-x_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

therefore

$$|xy-x_0y_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+ |x-x_0||y_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$
If this proof is correct, can't $|x - x_0| < min (\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}, 1)$ be replaced with $|x - x_0| < min (\frac{\varepsilon}{2|y_0|}, 1)$? Since the $+1$ term gets removed via the inequality.

Comment: Easier to start with $$xy-x_0y_0=x(y-y_0)+y_0(x-x_0)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, except for some minuscule, easily corrected mistakes.

- When you write $|x - x_0||y - y_0| < |y - y_0|$, you're assuming $y - y_0 \ne 0$.
- Your last inequality before the word "from" should be an equality.
- Your calculations after that assume $x - x_0 \ne 0$. By rearranging them so as to avoid division by $|x - x_0|$, this can be avoided.

You will make your life easier if you use $\leq$ whenever you don't really need $<$.

In answer to your last question, you're right, except that Spivak probably didn't want to bother saying what would happen in the special case $y_0 = 0$. The point of this exercise is not to find the sharpest bounds possible for $|x - x_0|$ and $|y - y_0|$, merely to exhibit bounds that work.